# AngularJS show error when submitting

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS step wizard and inside the form for the first step I need validation errors to appear when the use tries to hit submit. Right now I have the following:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="user.validate.step1.firstname.$invalid">Required Field</span>
```

But the error shows when I first goto the step and when I start typing in the field it goes away, I would like this to appear when the user tries to hit submit, not when they first goto the step. I already have this to indicate a required field

```
<span class="error">*</span>
```

Here is the full code:

```
<form name="user.validate.step1" novalidate>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="firstname" class="col-md-4 form-label">First Name:</label>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" value="{{user.firstname}}" ng-blur="blur1=true" required />
                                        <span class="error" ng-show="user.validate.step1.firstname.$invalid">*</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

keep in mind I have more than one input in this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the validation in the button using `ng-click="validateInputs()"` and create a var `invalidEntry` and a function `validateInputs()` to check if the input is valid or not. Something like this:

```
var inputs = [inputModel1,inputModel2,inputModel3];

function validateInputs(){
    invalidEntry = false;
    for(e in inputs){
        if(CheckInvalid(inputs[e])){
            invalidEntry = true;
            return;
        }
    }

}

function CheckValid(string){
    if(string == "" || string === null || string === undefined){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The submit button:

```
<button ng-click="validateInputs()">Submit</button>
```

And the span:

```
<span class="error" ng-show="invalidEntry">Required Field</span>
```

And the inputs should look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="inputModel1"></input>
<input type="text" ng-model="inputModel2"></input>
<input type="text" ng-model="inputModel3"></input>
```

Comment: Now I have multiple inputs like 10 of them, do I have to do this for each input? There has gotta be a better way.

Comment: I add a parameter to the function called `stringModel` to pass the value of the input and check if the string is valid or not. You can add an extra check to see if `stringModel == null` or `undefined`

Comment: I checked again what you say it, and fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should change ngShow in following way

```
ng-show="user.validate.step1.firstname.$invalid && !user.validate.step1.firstname.$pristine"
```

Check this article block [AngularJS Form Validation: Only Showing Errors After Submitting the Form](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation#only-showing-errors-after-submitting-the-form)

Comment: This does not work, the error still shows when I first goto the step

Comment: there as a small typo in second part , i've fixed it - **&& !user.validate.step1.firstname.$pristine**, mind the **.$pristine** (dot)

Comment: I tried your new code, the error does not appear when I first goto the page, but when I try to goto the next step and it doesnt show the input error

Comment: it's hard to guess all the details about you model and where exactly it went wrong, maybe try use **step1.firstname...** instead of **user.validate.step1.firstname....** depending how is you form name